# The circle is not contractible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I know that the circle is not contractible because I know that $\pi_1(S^1)\cong \mathbb Z$. But something is going wrong in my head. Choose a basepoint $*$ on the circle and chose an orientation (clockwise say) and for each point on the circle we take the path from that point to the base point $*$ going clockwise and making only one tour, meaning the first time we meet $*$ we stop. This seems to give us a continuous way to contract the circle onto $*$, making the circle contractible,  what is wrong with this reasoning ?

Comment: Is it really continuous at the basepoint $*$ itself ?

Comment: @paf GIven that he's talking about contractibility, he's referring to an informally described _family of_ maps. Each map in that family is continuous; that's not the problem. If he were claiming to have a retraction onto a point then yes, the problem would be that his contraction is not continuous at $*$.

Comment: @paf Actually, come to think of it, his description is "informal" enough that you could be right. I can think of a family of maps satisfying his description that tend to that constant uniformly, but which are not continuous. I can also think of a family of maps satisfying his description which _are_ continuous and tend to $*$ pointwise but not uniformly.

Comment: My understanding was that the OP was trying to define a map on $S^1 = \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ given by $f_t(x) = tx$.

Comment: Informally:  You're "ripping" the circle at the basepoint, so the map is not continuous.

Comment: @MartianInvader, that's a very good point. This characteristic of "ripping the space apart" should flow into the general intuitive visualization of what contractibility is: A space is contractible iff it can be shrunk to a point without ripping it apart anywhere, e.g. by having to move points around holes in different ways. My textbook did not make that point, so I fell into the same trap as OP did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to me that in the usual polar coordinates on the circle, OP is talking about the homotopy
$$
H: S^1 \times  [0, 1] \to S^1 : (\theta, s) \mapsto (1-s) \theta.
$$

For $s > 0$, this map is not continuous at $\theta = 0$, because no neighborhood of $0$ maps to a small neighborhood of $H(0, s)$. Hence it's not a deformation retraction from $S^1$ to a single point.

**Post-comment addition:**

Let's look at $s = \frac{1}{2}$. Fixing $s =\frac{1}{2}$, our map looks like

$$
\theta \mapsto H(\theta,\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} \theta.
$$
Let's therefore give it a name, and say
$$
f(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}\theta.
$$

Pick a small neighborhood of $0$, say, 
$$
U = (0 \le \theta < 0.1) \cup (2\pi - 0.1 < \theta < 2\pi)
$$

Under the map $f$, $0$ goes to $0$ (i.e., $f(0) = 0$). So the preimage of $U$, under $f$, i.e., $f^{-1}(U)$ should contain a neighborhood of $0$.

OK: small admission here. I should really be saying "for any neighborhood $U$ of $0$, there's a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ with the property that $f(V) \subset U$." Instead, I'm going to look at $f^{-1}(U)$ and note that it "looks wrong", i.e., that if doesn't contain any neighborhood $V$ of $0$.

What *is* $f^{-1}(U)$? Well, $U$ is a union of two parts. The preimage of the first part is 
$$
\{ \theta \mid 0 \le \theta < 0.2 \}.
$$
Clear enough, I hope.

The preimage of the second part is empty.

That means that the preimage of $U$ contains **no points** that are just below $2\pi$, hence it cannot contain any neighborhood of $\theta = 0$, since all neighborhoods of $\theta = 0$ contain points with $\theta$ arbitrarily near $2\pi$.

Comment: Thank you very much John !! this is the homotopy i have in mind. I just don't understand your sentence no neighborhood of 0 maps to a small neighborhood of $H(0,s)$, would you please explain it..

Comment: @palio: $\theta=0$ and $\theta=2\pi$ are the same point on $S^1$, so you should have $H(0,s)=H(2\pi,s)$ for all $s\in[0,1]$ for $H$ to be well-defined.

Comment: @palio: see post-comment edits.

Answer (score 3):

You have a family $(\gamma_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ of continuous maps from the circle to itself such that $\gamma_0$ is the identity, $\gamma_1$ is constant, and $\gamma_t\to\gamma_1$ *pointwise* is $t\to1$. But contractibility requires that $\gamma_t\to\gamma_1$ *uniformly*.

At least that's the way I read your description. It's sufficiently vague that it could be the family of maps you have in mind is not the one I thought you meant.

To clarify the ambiguity: Let's talk about the interval $[0,1]$ with the points $0$ and $1$ identified.

It could be you mean something like $$f_t(x)=x^{1-t}.$$That satisfies $f_0(x)=x$, $f_1(x)=1=0$, and each $f_t$ is continuous. That's what I was assuming above; the problem is that $f_t\to f_1$ pointwise but not uniformly.

Or it could be you mean something like $$f_t(x)=x(1-t),$$in which case $f_t\to f_1$ uniformly but $f_t$ is not continuous. (More accurately, $f_t$ is not even well-defined on our quotient space, since $f_t(0)\ne f_t(1)$. Defining a similar map on $[0,1)$ give something discontinuous, if we note that points close to $1$ are close to $0$.)

Comment: Yeah... I think you've misread his description. An alternative that seems to be what you're thinking of is something like $$K(\theta, s) = 2\pi \left( \frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right) ^ \frac{1}{1-s}$$ for $s \ne 1$, and everywhere $0$ for $s = 1$.

Comment: @JohnHughes I don't see how to tell which he meant from what he wrote.

Comment: Well, his "take a path" suggests a homotopy, since if OP just wanted to define a MAP form $S^1$ to $S^1$, OP'd have said "send $\theta$ to $0$ for every $\theta$. Which homotopy? Well, the one I've called "K" maps the circle onto itself at each $s<1$, but OP mentions no such thing. It also seems harder to come up with than the one I called $H$ in my answer. But you're right: there's no way to know for certain.

Comment: @JohnHughes Certainly it suggests a homotopy, as it should since he's talking about contracibility; hence my reply to the comment mentioning "_the_ map". But both those things are "wrong homotopies".

Comment: One note that surely clear to David, but had me baffled briefly as I read his answer, and so might confuse other novices: when David speaks of "uniformly", he's talking about uniform convergence, *not* uniform continuity, which is not a requirement for homotopies. For instance, the homotopy $L: \mathbb R^2 \times [0, 1] \to \mathbb R^2: (x, t) \mapsto tx$ is not uniformly continuous in $x$, but it *is* a deformation retraction from the plane to the origin.

Comment: @JohnHughes Not that it matters (I wonder if this question sets a record for explanations of why something's simply wrong) but: In that example we don't have uniform convergence either. Uniform convergence is not required for a homotopy, _a priori_. But if $K$ is a compact metric space and $H:K\times[0,1]\to K$ is continuous then $H$ is uniformly continuous, and hence $H(.,t)\to H(.,1)$ uniformly as $t\to1$. Pointing out the non-uniform nature of the convergence above seemed like the simplest way to explain why $F$ was not continuous, if $F(x,t)=f_t(x)$. I may have been wrong about that...

Comment: Ah...good point. I'm really weak on types of convergence and have to look things up every time, but I'm pretty solid on uniform continuity. :)  I figured that if uniformity of convergence depended on compactness, you'd have mentioned that, so I thought I was missing something. I was *going* to comment that "uniformity isn't the point unless your space is compact," but figured I was missing something. :)  Anyhow, I hope it's now pretty clear to both of us (and perhaps some others, too)!

Comment: @JohnHughes I think $L : \mathbb R^2 \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2 : (x,t) \mapsto tx$ is uniformaly continuous in $x$ (by which I suppose you mean that $t$ is fixed and $x$ varies), for then $| L(t,x) - L(t,y) | = t | x - y| \le |x-y| $ and we have even Lipschitz continuity, so contrary to what you are saying in the fifth comment...

Answer (score 3):

As you try this on points farther and farther along the way, you start approaching the point $*$ from the other side. To be continuous also there, you'd have to drag $*$ itself around the circle once, and then the points slightly past it once and a bit. But that's in contradiction to your rule that you only move them until you hit $*$ the first time. So your contraction will rip the circle right at the point $*$, violating continuity.

Comment: I think i see what you are saying !!

Answer (score 1):

it is not continuous at $*$. You construct an homotopy $H_t:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ such that $H_t(x)=c_t(x)$ where $c_t$ is the path going towards $*$ from $x$ clockwise. You must have $H_t(*)=*$. There exists a sequence $lim_nx_n=*$ anticlockwise such that $x_n\neq *$ and $lim_nH_t(x_n)=c_t(x_n)=*$ anticlockwise otherwise $H_t(S^1), t<1$ is homeomorphic to a non  closed interval. Impossible since the image of $S^1$ by $H_t$ has to be compact. Thus $H_t(S^1)=S^1, t<1$, this implies that $H_1(S^1)=S^1$ To see this let $x\in S^1$, and $t_n$ such that $lim_nt_n=1,t_n<1$ there $x_n$ such that $H_{t_n}(x_n)=x$. You can find a subsequence $x_{i(n)}$ of $x_n$ which converges towards $y$, $H_1(y)=lim_nH_{t_{i(n)}}(x_{i(n)})=x$. Contradiction since $H_1(S^1)=*$.